# How to create and save Excel file to DAM using java

Tags: java, adobe, aem, hssfworkbook

I am trying to create one excel sheet and save it into DAM.I am able to create excel in DAM, but no data is there in that excel. I am using following codes to create it.

```
String filename = "updatedMetadata.xls";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename));
WritableSheet writableSheet = workbook.createSheet("Updated Metadata", 0);
Label label = null;
label = new Label(0, 0, "Header1");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 1, "Header2");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 2, "Header3");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 3, "Header4");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 4, "Header5");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 5, "Header6");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 6, "Header7");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 7, "Header8");
writableSheet.addCell(label);                       
label = new Label(1, 0, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 1, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 2, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 3, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 4, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 5, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 6, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 7, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);                       
label = new Label(2, 0, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 1, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 2, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 3, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 4, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 5, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 6, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 7, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
workbook.write();
workbook.close();
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
AssetManager manager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class);
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/content/dam/company/fileFolder/" + filename);
Asset asset = manager.createAsset("/content/dam/company/fileFolder/" + filename, is, "application/vnd.ms-excel", true);
```

File is creating in this Path "/content/dam/company/fileFolder/"
File name is "updatedMetadata.xls"

Thanks in advance
Mahesh Narayanan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. I am sharing the code so that in future someone else can use it.

```
    String filename = "updatedMetadata.xls";
File excelFile = new File(filename);
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(excelFile);
WritableSheet writableSheet = workbook.createSheet("Updated Metadata", 0);

Label label = null;
label = new Label(0, 0, "Header1");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 1, "Header2");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 2, "Header3");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 3, "Header4");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 4, "Header5");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 5, "Header6");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 6, "Header7");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(0, 7, "Header8");
writableSheet.addCell(label);                       
label = new Label(1, 0, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 1, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 2, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 3, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 4, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 5, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 6, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(1, 7, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);                       
label = new Label(2, 0, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 1, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 2, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 3, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 4, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 5, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 6, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
label = new Label(2, 7, "col val");
writableSheet.addCell(label);
workbook.write();
workbook.close();
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
AssetManager manager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class);
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
Asset asset = manager.createAsset("/content/dam/company/fileFolder/" + filename, is, "application/vnd.ms-excel", true);
```